# Type should reference a specific enum or union using Apollo Graphql

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I'm trying to create what I thought would be a Union or Enum for Apollo GraphQL, however, my understanding is at noob level. What is the correct way to write the code below.

Path: `sampleType.graphql`

```
union GridSize = 'auto' | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12;

type Element {
  xs: GridSize
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to provide some states. For providing static states i recommend enums. Union types are for the repesentaion of the different types. E.G. `union GridSize = Int | String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL doesn't support string literals or numerical literals like you're doing. In TypeScript, for example, you can use literals like that:

```js
type GridSize = 'auto' | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12
```

GraphQL doesn't have anything like that. You can use enums:

```
enum GRID_SIZE {
  SOME_VALUE_HERE
  SECOND_OPTION
}
```

but unfortunately, your example won't work because the values in enums have to follow this regular expression `/[_A-Za-z][_0-9A-Za-z]*/`, which means it can't start with (or be only) a number.

---

So what can you do?

You can use [Dani R's commented answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69578405/type-should-reference-a-specific-enum-or-union-using-apollo-graphql#comment122992040_69578405), and just create a union that accepts an `Int | String`. This is the easiest thing. Alternatively, if you want to make this its own type "for real" – which acts the way you're describing it (mostly) – you can create a custom scalar:

```
"""
The following values are accepted
'auto' | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12
"""
scalar GridSize

type Element {
  xs: GridSize
}
```

Then you need to create your scalar resolvers:

```js
const { GraphQLScalarType, Kind } = require('graphql')
const allowedValues = ['auto', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

const gridSizeScalar = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'GridSize',
  description: `
  The following values are accepted
  'auto' | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12
  `,
  serialize(value) {
    // outgoing from your code
    if (!allowedValues.includes(value)) {
      // or you could throw, but your own code had better not return bad values :)
      console.error('something')
      return null
    }
    return value
  },
  parseValue(value) {
    // incoming from input
    if (!allowedValues.includes(value)) {
      // you probably have a better error message than I do
      throw new RangeError('Not a valid Grid Size')
    }
    return value
  },
  parseLiteral(ast) {
    if ((ast.kind !== Kind.INT) && (ast.kind !== Kind.STRING)) {
      // if this value isn't a string or number, it's definitely not OK
      return null
    }
    return ast.value
  }
})
```

and just stick that in your resolvers

```js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {},
  Mutation: {},
  Whatever: {},
  GridSize: gridSizeScalar
}
```